# jquery class prefix name selection with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok i have a problem with selecting class with prefix name using variable. 
This is my code:

```
$('.product_type').on("click", function(event) {
  type_id = event.target.id;
  $("div[class*='product_']").fadeOut("fast");
  var dbg = $("div[class*='product_']") + type_id;
  dbg.fadeIn("fast");
  $('#echo').text(show_ids);
});
```

Problem is at `var dbg = $("div[class*='product_']") + type_id;`
Selection is not working when I add variable `+ type_id`...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) It's not clear what you're asking to do. Are you trying to add the contents of `type_id` onto the class in the selector? Or...? It's often helpful if you post a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: Without your HTML, and without a clear description of the problem, we are mostly unable to help you, or any future visitors, without making guesses and assumptions.

Comment: In this case, though, you're adding the string variable `type_id` to a jQuery object. If you want to add it to the selector, add it to the string inside of `$()`.

Comment: I try that but not working... `var dbg = $("div[class*='product_']" + type_id);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you want to use var `dbg = $("div[class*='product_" + type_id + "']");` instead of var `dbg = $("div[class*='product_']") + type_id;`

i think your mistake is added your name after getting object

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code, you were missing the var declaration and you can just append inside the `$()`

```
$('.product_type').on("click", function(event) {
    var type_id = event.target.id;
    $("div.product_" + type_id).fadeOut("fast");
    var dbg = $("div.product_" + type_id);
    dbg.fadeIn("fast");
    $('#echo').text(show_ids); // i don't know what this line makes, just copied it from your code
});
```